# Find tokens that are connected

Tags: python, token

I wrote code that gets text-tokens as input:

```
tokens = ["Tap-", "Berlin", "Was-ISt", "das", "-ist", "cool", "oh", "Man", "-Hum", "-Zuh-UH-", "glit"]
```

The code should find all tokens that contain hyphens or are connected to each other with hyphens: Basically the output should be:

```
[["Tap-", "Berlin"], ["Was-ISt"], ["das", "-ist"], ["Man", "-Hum", "-Zuh-UH-", "glit"]]
```

I wrote a code, but somehow Im not getting the with hypens connected  Tokens back: To try it out: http://goo.gl/iqov0q

```
def find_hyphens(self):
    tokens_with_hypens =[]


    for i in range(len(self.tokens)):

        hyp_leng = 0

        while self.hypen_between_two_tokens(i + hyp_leng):
            hyp_leng += 1

        if self.has_hypen_in_middle(i) or hyp_leng > 0:
            if hyp_leng == 0:
                tokens_with_hypens.append(self.tokens[i:i + 1])
            else:
                tokens_with_hypens.append(self.tokens[i:i + hyp_leng])
                i += hyp_leng - 1

    return tokens_with_hypens
```

**What do I wrong? Is there a more performant solution? Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 3 mistakes in your code:

1) You are comparing the last 2 characters of `tok1` here, rather than the last of `tok1` and the first of `tok2`:

```
if "-" in joined[len(tok1) - 2: len(tok1)]:
# instead, do this:
if "-" in joined[len(tok1) - 1: len(tok1) + 1]:
```

2) You are omitting the last matching token here. Increase the end-index of your slice here by 1:

```
tokens_with_hypens.append(self.tokens[i:i + hyp_leng])
# instead, do this:
tokens_with_hypens.append(self.tokens[i:i + 1 + hyp_leng])
```

3) You cannot manipulate the index of a `for i in range` loop in python. the next iteration will just retrieve the next index, overwriting your change. Instead, you could use a while-loop like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(self.tokens):
    [...]
    i += 1
```

These 3 corrections lead to your test passing: http://goo.gl/fd07oL

---

Nonetheless I couldn't resist to write an algorithm from scratch, solving your problem as simple as possible:

```
def get_hyphen_groups(tokens):
    i_start, i_end = 0, 1
    while i_start < len(tokens):
        while (i_end < len(tokens) and
              (tokens[i_end].startswith("-") ^ tokens[i_end - 1].endswith("-"))):
            i_end += 1
        yield tokens[i_start:i_end]
        i_start, i_end = i_end, i_end + 1


tokens = ["Tap-", "Berlin", "Was-ISt", "das", "-ist", "cool", "oh", "Man", "-Hum", "-Zuh-UH-", "glit"]

for group in get_hyphen_groups(tokens):
    print ("".join(group))
```

To exclude 1-element-groups, like in your expected result, wrap the `yield` into this `if`:

```
if i_end - i_start > 1:
    yield tokens[i_start:i_end]
```

To include 1-element-groups that already include a hyphen, change that `if` to this for example:

```
if i_end - i_start > 1 or "-" in tokens[i_start]:
    yield tokens[i_start:i_end]
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is wrong with your approach is trying to change the value of `i` in the `for i in range(len(self.tokens))` loop. It won't work because the value of `i` will get the next value from `range` in each iteration, ignoring your changes.

I changed your algorithm to use an iterative algorithm that pops one item at the time from the list and decides what to do with it. It uses a buffer where it stored items belonging to one chain until it's complete.

The full code is:

```
class Hyper:

    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def find_hyphens(self):
        tokens_with_hypens =[]

        copy = list(self.tokens)

        buffer = []
        while len(copy) > 0:
            item = copy.pop(0)
            if self.has_hyphen_in_middle(item) and item[0] != '-' and item[-1] != '-':
                # words with hyphens that are not part of a bigger chain
                tokens_with_hypens.append([item])
            elif item[-1] == '-' or (len(copy) > 0 and copy[0][0] == '-'):
                # part of a chain - append to the buffer
                buffer.append(item)
            elif len(buffer) > 0:
                # the last word in a chain - the buffer contains the complete chain
                buffer.append(item)
                tokens_with_hypens.append(buffer)
                buffer = []

        return tokens_with_hypens

    @staticmethod
    def has_hyphen_in_middle(input):
        return len(input) > 2 and "-" in input[1:-2]


tokens = ["Tap-", "Berlin", "Was-ISt", "das", "-ist", "cool", "oh", "Man", "-Hum", "-Zuh-UH-", "glit"]

hyper = Hyper(tokens)

result = hyper.find_hyphens()

print(result)

print(result == [["Tap-", "Berlin"], ["Was-ISt"], ["das", "-ist"], ["Man", "-Hum", "-Zuh-UH-", "glit"]])
```